# Need to change container's colors temporarily

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container that functions as a button. Upon clicking the container, a bottom modal sheet pops up from the bottom. How do I make it so that the container's background color and elements inside the color temporarily change color while the bottom modal sheet is up and displayed? Please note I do not wish to change the container of the bottom modal sheet itself.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can do following

1. Create a variable in your state class which is equals to the color of the container. Initially it will be the color you want to show the user when button is active.
2. Once, button is clicked, just before calling showBottomModalSheet, change color value and call setState.
3. You can await `showBottomModalSheet` and reverse back to original color and call setState afterwards.

You will have to make you onPressed/onTap async method.